# how to change UINavigationBar light

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I am quite new to iOS development and its my first time styling things here.

before anyone says anything I know that the following code will change the colour

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.169 green:0.373 blue:0.192 alpha:0.9];
```

What I want to do is I would like to change the light in the nav bar. Currently is the default one that comes as a gradient top to bottom. But What I want to do is to change it so that it glows like the picture, in the middle only.

I don't know if I am better off using a picture or drawing the light with xcode would be the best option. mainly due memory consumption and effectivity. My guess is that drawing the light would be the best option, i just need to know how to do it.

I tried searching for this but probably my lack of iOS dev knowledge is stopping me from finding the right tutorial or code sample on how to do this.

Any help is appreciated it.

[image]

this is another example that the light distribution is different from the default UINavBar. I really wonder if they used a picture or drew it with xCode

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/) as is the best way draw and image using code which is as memory efficient as a normal image but given that is in code it allows high degree of customisation to the image. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521992/what-consumes-less-memory-an-actual-image-or-a-drawn-image) for a post about memory in draw images

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use a custom image for the bar rather than "draw" the glow.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a custom image, and try this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:yourImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
```

add this code in your app delegate, it works as global settings, all the navigation bar will be set

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{     
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.imgBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 [self.window addSubview:self.imgBackgroundView];
    [self addCustomNavigationController];
[self addCustomNavigationController];
}

- (void)addCustomNavigationController
{
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    if ([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)])
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[self getImageFromResource:@"topbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
          UITextAttributeTextColor,
          [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],
          UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
          [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],
          UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
          [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.0],
          UITextAttributeFont,
          nil]];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Login" forKey:@"randomView"];
}

- (UIImage*)getImageFromResource:(NSString*)imageName
{
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please Use appearance for iOS5 and iOS6
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.08 green:0.72 blue:0.78 alpha:1]];

Answer (score 0):

one alternate solution can be to add a UIButton on the NavigationBar.

set its Shows touch on highlight property from the attributes inspector or using

```
[buttonGlow setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```

and in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[buttonGlow setHighlighted:YES];
```